# We gonna get out out beta very soon; And just in time!

Tags: discussion

Loads of UK high street and major on line computer stores are starting to sell bundled Pi's

This means that that all those newbie people are going to be asking the same questions we all have. Cha-ching for us. Traffic is going explode- good thing that search engines already cached the most popular question.

It is going to be interesting :)

Comment: This is great news for the foundation too :)

Comment: Why you say *soon*? Is there a date? I see the vitals for questions/day are still low.

Comment: Yea.. its going to go mental ... "on a plate"

Answer (score 5):

Are we actually getting out of beta soon or are you just assuming we are? I'm looking forward to it as much as anyone, but I don't think we're quite there yet on two counts:

- Questions per day is still under 3. We need about 5 times that to make it to the green light.
- We don't have enough high rep users to moderate the community - yup there'll be diamond mods, but at the moment most people are a fair way off from having enough rep to help them out (excluding Jivings who's a diamond mod, the next person in line is only on 5k, and it drops off pretty steeply from there.)

Comment: Still good- questions will roll in once all more newbies get their Pi's and that means more rep for us all. Soon is better never...